# TeamCity setup to pull from HG (Mercurial)

Tags: mercurial, msbuild, teamcity

I need to set up TeamCity (I'm a super beginner with this beast that is called TeamCity).

Just to get things going, I want to be able to Pull from a few repositories from Mercurial (So I can see where they're pulled into, so I can move into setting up the build steps)

This is what I've done so far:

1. created the project
2. Setup the VCS bit (Test connection works; so I know Mercurial is properly working)

I want to test this setup by clicking the "Run..." button so I see the files are being pulled from mercurial

**The problem** is I don't see the "Run..." button. how can I go about this

> Create a build step to simply pull data from mercurial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity will not pull the changes or run the build unless at least one build step is defined. To test that your sources are pulled correctly you can, for example, add build step of type 'CommandLine' with some sample script (ex 'echo "Hello, World!"') inside.

After this build step is added, you should be able to run your build configuration

Comment: oh right, thanks for the reply; yeah I figured out how to set everything up; your answer is correct though, so thanks :)